# Error " Unexpected token" when export multiple typescript type alias from a ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-export-question-tlbd2

error will be on `export type {`

```
type abc = {
  a: string;
};

type bbc = {bbb: string}

export type {
  abc,
  bbc,
}
```

Is exporting types something not suppose to be done? I am trying to reuse types as much as I can. If there is better alternatives plz let me know

Comment: That sandbox is using an outdated version of TS. your code works [as is](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=12#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgRgYygXigbwFBVgLigZ2ACcBLAOwHMBuDAXxo1EijkRXVbj0NMtowwQAHmAD2RYFCbRM2eAgA0WFoiW0gAhttps://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=12#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgRgYygXigbwFBVgLigZ2ACcBLAOwHMBuDAXxo1EijkRXVbj0NMtowwQAHmAD2RYFCbRM2eAgA0WFoiW0gA). However, there's no need to point in using `type` keyword in this case because they are already just type names with no presence in the value space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to export the types so that you can import them like this:

```js
import { abc, bbc } from './my-types';
```

You can simply export when declaring them:

```js
export type abc = {
  a: string;
};

export type bbc = {bbb: string}
```

But you might also be looking for TypeScript `namespace`, if that is the case please look at the [documentation here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think your only issue is adding the keyword `type` to your export:

```
type abc = {
  a: string;
};

type bbc = {bbb: string}

export { abc, bbc }
```

Does this work for you or do you still get the same error?

Comment: no. I tried this first, I am getting `'abc' is not defined.eslintno-undef
Re-exporting a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided requires using 'export type'.` for both types

Comment: Can you share your `tsconfig.json` and `eslint.rc` files?